# PugJs - file not found / no such file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

my first time learning `pugJs` and using command prompt and I have this error
Error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\aya'

[It is image of error in command prompt after running](https://prnt.sc/pbzpqq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to put the address in the "address" than the address where the command should be executed from the space used.

```
pug --watch "C:\Users\aya hosny\Desktop\Desktop\pug"
```

Comment: please accept my answer, for bounty or up vote. that  another person use this answer